# SQL Update Statement With conditions

Tags: java, sql

i'm creating a method in my java application which can update data in a database according to three user inputs which are,

**Column_name ,
 New_value ,
 Condition**

```
UPDATE sportsclub SET '"Column_name"' = '"New_value"' WHERE club_id = '"Condition"'
```

Thing is the code is working without the (SET '"Column_name"') part. Is there any other way to do it or am I doing something wrong?
Column Name is a variable actually. I get a string input from the user for eg: he wants to update the age column so he types "age", and another person wants to change the height column so he types "height" through a scanner method.

I need to update a record in any column the user inputs.

Comment: `UPDATE sportsclub SET Column_name = 'New_value' WHERE club_id = 'club_id_value'`

Comment: Column Name is a variable actually. I get a string input from the user for eg: he wants to update the age column so he types "age", and another person wants to change the height column so he types "height" through a scanner class.

Comment: "UPDATE sportsclub SET "+ Column_name+" = '"+New_value+"' WHERE club_id = '"+Condition+"'";

Comment: I am not familiar with JAVA. But you can line inline query like posted above. Also you can use `prepared statement`. (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Column_name ,New_value and Condition are variable,
They must be concatenated properly otherwise they will be treated as String and not variables.

Use this,

```
"UPDATE sportsclub SET "+ Column_name+" = '"+New_value+"' WHERE club_id = '"+Condition+"'";
```

Comment: Thank You Very much, Your  Advice Worked.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE sportsclub SET "+ Column_name+" = '"+New_value+"' WHERE club_id = '"+value+"'";